# Existence of a fundamental domain for the convex hull of group action on a rational polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-analysis, arithmetic-groups

Let $P \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact rational polytope (the affine space spanned by $P$ may not be $\mathbb R^n$). Let $G \subset {\bf GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ be an arithmetic group. Let $$C = {\rm Conv}(\bigcup_{g\in G} \ g\cdot P)$$ be the convex hull.

**Question**: does there exist a compact rational polytope $Q \subset C$ such that $\bigcup_{g\in G}\ g\cdot Q = C$ ?

Comment: Is a rational polytope a polytope with rational vertex coordinates?

Comment: I assume that you want $(g\cdot Q)\cap (g'\cdot Q)$ to be of a lower dimension as $C$ if $g\not=g'$, as otherwise just choose $Q:=C$, right?

Comment: 1. Rational polytope means a polytope which is the convex hull of finite rational points. 2. No. $Q$ may not be compact (and may not be a polytope). Here I only need a compact rational polytope $Q$. After knowing this, I can get a fundamental domain by Looijenga's paper "Discrete automorphism groups of convex cones of finite type" Application 4.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that by an "arithmetic group" you mean a subgroup $\Gamma$ commensurable to the intersection $GL(n, {\mathbb Z})\cap G$, where $G< GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ is an algebraic subgroup defined over a number field $F$; actually, $F={\mathbb Q}$ will suffice for my purposes. (I prefer to use Greek letters to denote arithmetic subgroups, as it is customary in the literature.)

I will even assume that $G$ is semisimple (which you are probably implicitly assuming). I claim that, in general, $Q$ does not exist.

The example will be given by $n=3, G=O(2,1)$, the stabilizer of the quadratic form $q=-x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2$. I will use $\Gamma<G\cap GL(3, {\mathbb Z})$, the index two subgroup preserving the open future light cone
$$
L_+=\{x: q(x)<0, x_0>0\}.$$
Take
$p=(1,0,0)$ and $P=\{p\}$. Then the orbit $\Gamma \cdot p$ is an unbounded subset of  $L_+$. Moreover, for each point $x$ in the convex hull $C$ of this orbit, $C$ also contains the cone $x+ L_+$. This is because $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$ and, hence, the closure of the projection of $\Gamma x$ to ${\mathbb R} P^2$ contains the quadric
$$
P(\{q(x)=0\})\subset {\mathbb R} P^2. 
$$
In particular, $q$ is unbounded from below on $C$.

Now, if $Q\subset L_+$ is any compact subset, then its $G$-orbit (hence, $\Gamma$-orbit) is contained in a region
$$
\{x\in L_+: a\le q(x)\le b\}
$$
where
$$
a= \max q|_Q, b=\min q|_Q.
$$
Hence, no bounded subset $Q$ of $L_+$ will satisfy the containment
$$
C\subset \Gamma \cdot Q. 
$$
If $Q$ is not contained in $L_+$, then we of course cannot have the other containment
$$
\Gamma \cdot Q\subset C. 
$$

If yo allow reductive groups $G$, then one can even get an example with $n=2$.

However, maybe by an "arithmetic group" you simply mean a finite index subgroup $\Gamma$ of $GL(n, {\mathbb Z})$. Then one can prove that for every $P$ either $C={\mathbb R}^n$ or $P=C=\{0\}$. In this case, $Q$ of course exists and for $C={\mathbb R}^n$ you can take $Q$ to be any convex polytope whose interior contains the origin.

Comment: I use your first definition of arithmetic group (in my case, it is never a finite index subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb Z$). However, I don't understand your example: suppose you take $Q$ such that $p \in Q \subset L_+$, isn't that $\Gamma \cdot Q$ is unbounded (as you claim $\Gamma \cdot p$ is unbounded)?

Comment: @LiYutong The key thing to understand is that $q$ is unbounded (from below) on $C$ and bounded from below on $\Gamma\cdot Q$. Of course, $q$ is constant on $\Gamma\cdot p$.

Comment: I see your point. Could you explain why : $C$ also contains the cone $x+L_+$? Suppose you know the image under the projection through $p$ is $\{q=0\} \subset R\mathbb P^2$ (which I also don't know why $\Gamma$ is a lattice imply this), how to know its preimage contains  $x+L_+$?

Comment: @LiYutong When I get back to my computer. For now, think about action of a cyclic hyperbolic group on p: You see a biinfinite sequence tracing a hyperbola. Now, take the convex hull of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that $G$ is finite. We can then assume that $G$ consists of orthogonal transformations (just use a $G$-invariant inner product).

Choose a point $x\in\Bbb Q^n$ that is not fixed by any non-identity $g\in G$.
Consider the [*Voronoi decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of $\Bbb R^n$ w.r.t. the orbit $G\cdot x$.
Some thought reveals that the Voronoi cells are cones with apex at the origin and spanned by rational vectors.
Furthermore, $G$ acts regularly (that is, transitively and freely) on the cells.

If $R$ is one such Voronoi cell, then set $Q:=R\cap C$. Then indeed

$$C=\bigcup_{g\in G} g\cdot Q,$$

and, while not explicitly requested, we also have that $g\cdot G$ and $g'\cdot G$ meet only in a *proper* face whenever $g\not=g'$.

$Q$ is the intersection of a rational cone with a rational polytope, thus, itself rational.

[image]

The image shows an example where $G$ is the cyclic group generated by a $90^\circ$ rotation.

Comment: The issue is that the action on $R^n$ is never isometric/properly discontinious unless $G$ is finite, so Voronoi tilings are highly problematic (they will not be $G$-invariant).  The extreme case is of subgroups commensurable with $GL(n,Z)$ itself: They all act ergodically, so almost every orbit is dense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree (and I just realize) that I make some unstated assumptions. One is that $G$ is finite. I also think that I get problems if some $g\in G$ is not orthogonal. I guess I will leave the answer for what it is, even if it might miss the point.

Comment: Non-orthogonal is not a big deal if $G$ is finite: You can always find a $G$-invariant inner product (by averaging) and use it to define your metric. You may want to state your finiteness assumption explicitly in your answer, maybe OP is interested in this case.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you for your answer, however, the group $G$ in my case is an infinite group.